# Spark taskset concurrent stage submission

Tags: apache-spark, concurrency, task, scheduler, directed-acyclic-graphs

Suppose a spark job has two stages with independent dependencies (they do not depend on each other) and they are submitted concurrently/simultaneously (as Tasksets) by the   DAG scheduler to the task scheduler. Can someone give more detailed insight on how the cores available on executors are distributed among the two ready stages/Tasksets? More precisely:

- Tasks from  the second taskset/stage are not launched until the tasks of the previous taskset/stage complete? or,
- Tasks from both tasksets can be launched (granted cores) simultaneously depending depending on the logic implemented by the taskscheduler e.g. FIFO/Fair?

In general suppose a new resource offer has triggered the taskscheduler to make decision to select some ready tasks (out of n ready taksets) for execution? what is the logic implemented by the taskscheduler in such case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the scheduling mode that is in use. In
TaskSchedulerImpl.scala the constructor parses the scheduling mode
based on the flag "spark.scheduler.mode". The default is FIFO in which
case all the cores are first given to the first taskset before being
offered to the second taskset.